# Subsonic in Medium trust level

Tags: asp.net, sqlite, subsonic

i host my web site in shared hosting server, this server use the default Medium trust level

When i execute this

ConfigurationDataCollection configurationDatumCollection = new ConfigurationDataCollection().Where(ConfigurationData.Columns.Name, configurationSectionName).Load();

i get this error

That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.

at SubSonic.ELib3DataProvider.GetReader(QueryCommand qry)
   at SubSonic.DataService.GetReader(QueryCommand cmd)
   at SubSonic.Query.ExecuteReader()
   at SubSonic.AbstractList`2.Load()

How i can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUbSonic 2.x works in medium trust just fine - provided you're not using the BuildProvider. The Enterprise Library, however, has problems:
http://www.codeplex.com/entlib/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=8832

I think your configuration on Ent. Lib needs to be tweaked, or you can toss it altogether and probably fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Rob

Before i has in web.config

```
<SubSonicService defaultProvider="ELib2DataProvider"> 
<providers> 
<add name="ELib2DataProvider" type="SubSonic.ELib2DataProvider, SubSonic" connectionStringName="CommerceTemplate"/> 
</providers> 
</SubSonicService>
```

and i change for this

```
<SubSonicService defaultProvider="SqlDataProvider"> 
<providers> 
<add name="SqlDataProvider" type="SubSonic.SqlDataProvider, SubSonic" connectionStringName="CommerceTemplate"/> 
</providers> 
</SubSonicService>
```

And run in Medium trust level